# Hard disk failure

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, windows-7, sony

I have a sony vaio laptop 500GB hard disk i5 4GB ram .

I had dual booted my machine with major portion as windows  and just a 20GB ubuntu partition.

Then one day i dropped my laptop which kind of damaged the hard disk. I could still run ubuntu but not windows. So i used the windows recovery enviroment and reinstalled windows .

By this windows 7 started working but awfully slow . The pc wud get stuck if i tried running any application and when turned off forcefully it would restart into grub rescue everytime telling either 'No operating System Found '  or 'error attempt to write outside hd0' and some other errors .

The problem was the hard disk. The fall had created many bad sectors in the hard disk memory. So after looking through internet i did a chkdsk -r  on cmd  and this fixed the bad sectors temporarily.

But then one day the machine got stuck again and when i tried to restart the machine it said "SMART disk check failed back up your data"

Somehow i logged in ubuntu  and formatted the hard disk thinking it would solve the bad sector or errors in hard disk . It got formatted. So now i didnt have any OS on my machine. I used an USB to boot into ubuntu  and when i tried installing ubuntu on hard disk it wont allow me .

I know i have to buy a new hard disk. But till then i need to use my machine

What should i do ?

Comment: I don't know what kind of advice you want to get, when you already know what to do.

Comment: Is there any way to temporarily patch the hard disk so that i can install ubuntu . Im using live usb currently .So im wondering if there are any memory repair commands which i could run

Comment: @jeffdevasia you can't "patch" physical damage. The discs in the drive are very likely scratched, which is irreparable, and it's a bad idea to continue trying to write to the disk.

Answer (score 3):

Your HDD is about to kick the bucket. You need to get a new one immediately.

You cannot run an OS on a failing HDD.

Your only option is to run off of a live USB drive.